# How to extract new substring as column columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv

I have a pandas dataframe
a colum named: entity
when I print the column via:

```
df.entity
```

The output looks like this (I have 267 rows this is just the first two rows)

```
[(East, NNP), (India, CTR), (Company, ORG)]
[(Pasteur, ZZP)]
```

How can I get a new column where the output is like:

```
East, India, Company
Pasteur
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
`zip` and iterators

```
df.assign(entity=[', '.join(next(zip(*r))) for r in df.entity])

                 entity
0  East, India, Company
1               Pasteur
```

---

**Option 2**
A comprehension verion of @Zero's answer.  Should be quicker.

```
df.assign(entity=[', '.join([x[0] for x in r]) for r in df.entity])

                 entity
0  East, India, Company
1               Pasteur
```

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    entity=[
        [('East', 'NNP'), ('India', 'CTR'), ('Company', 'ORG')],
        [('Pasteur', 'ZZP')]
    ]))
```

Comment: Two `for loop` :) nice

Comment: @Zero functionally the same, but I'd use comprehensions over `apply` almost always

Answer (score 2):

Use `apply`

```
In [4697]: df.entity.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(t[0] for t in x))
Out[4697]:
0    East, India, Company
1                 Pasteur
Name: entity, dtype: object
```

---

Details

```
                                        entity
0  [(East, NNP), (India, CTR), (Company, ORG)]
1                             [(Pasteur, ZZP)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution

```
df['New']=df.entity.apply(pd.Series).stack().apply(pd.Series).groupby(level=0)[0].agg(lambda x: ','.join(set(x)))
df
Out[74]: 
                                        entity                 New
0  [(East, NNP), (India, CTR), (Company, ORG)]  India,Company,East
1                             [(Pasteur, ZZP)]             Pasteur
```

Data Input

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'entity':[[('East', 'NNP'), ('India', 'CTR'), ('Company', 'ORG')],[('Pasteur', 'ZZP')] ]})
```

Comment: TypeError: Argument 'obj' has incorrect type (expected list, got Tree)
I receive this error

Comment: @jenniferruurs added my input data